# Orientação a Objetos Python

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos

Como fazer com que a única maneira de inserir os dias, meses e anos sejam única e exclusivamente feito pelo método setDia() ou seja, quando for instanciar não quero passar valores para esses atributos naquele momento.

Segue código abaixo:

```
class Data():

def __init__(self, dia = 1, mes = 1, ano = 1980):
    self._dia = dia
    self._mes = mes
    self._ano = ano
    if not self._valida(): #Depois que os dados sao passados para os atributos, chamamos a funcao de validacao para validar os dados
        raise ValueError('Erro! Data invalida.')

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.getDia()}/{self.getMes()}/{self.getAno()}'

def _valida(self):
    if not 1 <= self._dia <= 31:
        return False
    if not 1 <= self._mes <= 12:
        return False
    if self._ano < 1:
        return False
    return True

def eAnterior(self, dataComp):
    if dataComp.getAno() > self.getAno():
        return False
    elif dataComp.getAno() == self.getAno() and dataComp.getMes() > self.getMes():
        return False
    elif dataComp.getAno() == self.getAno() and dataComp.getMes() == self.getMes() and dataComp.getDia() >= self.getDia():
        return False
    else:
        return True

def ePosterior(self, dataComp):
    if dataComp.getAno() < self.getAno():
        return False
    elif dataComp.getAno() == self.getAno() and dataComp.getMes() < self.getMes():
        return False
    elif dataComp.getAno() == self.getAno() and dataComp.getMes() == self.getMes() and dataComp.getDia() <= self.getDia():
        return False
    else:
        return True

def eSimultaneo(self, dataComp):
    if dataComp.getAno() != self.getAno():
        return False
    elif dataComp.getAno() == self.getAno() and dataComp.getMes() != self.getMes():
        return False
    elif dataComp.getAno() == self.getAno() and dataComp.getMes() == self.getMes() and dataComp.getDia() != self.getDia():
        return False
    else:
        return True    

def setData(self, dia, mes, ano):
    TODO: 'Preciso fazer com que essa funcao se torne a unica maneira de setar os atributos, sendo todos ou apenas um ou dois.'
    self._dia = dia
    self._mes = mes
    self._ano = ano
    if not self._valida():
        self._dia = 1
        self._mes = 1
        self._ano = 1980
        raise ValueError('Erro! Data invalida.')

@property
def _dia(self):
    return self._dia

@property
def _mes(self):
    return self._mes

@property
def _ano(self):
    return self._mes

@dia.setter
def _dia(self, dia):
    self._dia = dia
    self._valida()

@mes.setter    
def _mes(self, mes):
    self._mes = mes
    self._valida()

@ano.setter
def _ano(self, ano):
    self.ano = ano
    self._valida()
```

E esse mesmo código, quando eu tento executa-lo ele me devolve um erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Data.py", line 1, in <module>
 class Data():
File "Data.py", line 75, in Data
 @dia.setter
NameError: name 'dia' is not defined
```

Mas o `dia`, está setado lá em cima no `__init__`.

Comment: o erro se refere ao setter e não á propriedade, o problema esta nos nomes das funções setter e getter, use get_dia para a função getter, @get_dia.setter para o decorador

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acho deve fazer o setter e getter de outra forma, fiz um exemplo simples para demonstração

```
class GetSet:
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self._valor = arg

    @property
    def valor(self):
        return self._valor

    @valor.setter
    def valor(self, arg):
        self._valor = arg
```

E a forma de fazer uso

```
teste = GetSet(10)
print(teste.valor)
teste.valor = 15
print(teste.valor)
```